# TargetProject in .Net Rally API 2.0 is NULL

Tags: rally

```
Request request = new Request("Milestone");
  request.Project = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootProject"];
        request.ProjectScopeDown = true;
        request.Fetch = new List<string>() 
        { 
            "ObjectId",
            "FormattedID",
            "Name",
            "TargetDate",
            "c_ApplicationName",
            "c_Type",
            "TargetProject",
            "TotalArtifactCount",
            "Notes",
            "c_ProductName"
        };
```

QueryResult queryResult = Api.Query(r);

The TargetProject is coming as NULL for some Milestones, whereas the Project is selected in UI for Rally. This is not the case with all Milestones though. Not sure why some do not have this value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a holdover from some changes in the way milestones are linked to projects.  The TargetProject attribute is deprecated and should no longer be used.  Milestones now either have an empty Projects collection (workspace wide) or a specific set of projects.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to fetch all the milestones under a project and its sub projects? I have tried with "Projects contains /project/<<project_id>>", but it does not return the milestones where all the projects are selected. Can we call a single API which returns all the milestones under a project and also where all the projects are selected?